# It is true that $A \cap B\cap C \subset A-(B-C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

I tried to make a counterexample, but didn't find it. So I tried to prove it

The statement says: let A, B and C be subsets of X. It is true that $A \cap B\cap C \subset A-(B-C)$?

I did the following

Suppose $A \cap B\cap C \not\subset  A-(B-C)$

Let $x \in A \cap B\cap C$

$\implies  x \in \text{A }  \land x \in \text{B }  \land x \in \text{C } $

$\implies x \not \in A-(B-C)$

$\implies x \not \in \text{A }  \land x \in \text{B }  \land x \not \in \text{C } $

This is absurd

$\therefore A \cap B\cap C \subset A-(B-C)$

Comment: Have you drawn a Venn diagram?

Comment: Hint : $X\setminus Y=X\cap Y^c.$

Comment: **Note** An element is not in a set difference when it is not in the included set **or** in the excluded set.  $${x\notin U\smallsetminus V}\iff {x\notin U\lor x\in V}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your second "$\implies$" is incorrect. Try this instead: If $x$ is in $A \cap B \cap C$, then $x$ is in $A$, and $x$ is *not* in $B -C$ [because $x$ is in $C$ and $B-C$ are the elements in $B$ that are also *not* in $C$]. Then, that $x$ is in $A$ and $x$ is *not* in $B-C$, implies that $x$ must be in $A-(B-C)$.

So it follows that if $x$ is in $A \cap B \cap C$, then $x$ is in $A$ and $x$ is not in $B-C$, which in turn implies that $x$ is in $A-(B-C)$. So then, if $x$ is in $A \cap B \cap C$, then $x$ is in $A -(B-C)$. Can you finish from here.

Comment: +1  This answer is fine but I"d like to add, after "Your second "$\implies$" is incorrect," some advice to the OP:  Make sure you understand why it's incorrect. That may be more important in the long run than the answer to this particular problem.